# Action Bar Search in collapsing Toolbar Layout

Tags: android, android-actionbar, menuitem, android-menu, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I have a CollapsingToolbarLayout with recycler view. In my actionbar I have a search menu item. But whenever I click search icon, the edittext layout do not appear.

Screenshots:- 
A) When search is not clicked
[image: Initially]

B) When Search icon is clicked
[image: After Click]

My main_activity.xml code:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main_id"
    tools:context="objectdistance.ankeshkjaisansaria.ram.sita.cameratag.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/app_bar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">


        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:expandedTitleMarginStart="48dp"
            app:expandedTitleMarginEnd="64dp"
            android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/imagetoolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="200dp"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>


    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>




    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />



</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

In my activity.java the search item is handled this way:-

```
        ActionBar action = getSupportActionBar(); //get the actionbar
        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true); //enable it to display a
        // custom view in the action bar.
        action.setCustomView(R.layout.search_bar);//add the custom view
        action.setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false); //hide the title
```

But the search_bar layout is not appearing only. And also the title is not hiding.

**Is there any different way to handle search in menu item when using collapsing layout ?**

Comment: Post your code also.

Comment: Have you added item for `Search View` in `menu.xml` or in any of your custom menu `XML` ?

Comment: @jaydroider I have edited my question showing screenshots. I get the search icon and every thing. The only issue is the the edittext is not getting displayed.

Comment: Yes i have checked your screen shot . have you given required permission in `manifest` or not.

Comment: @jaydroider which permission

Comment: `<meta-data android:name="android.app.searchable"
            android:resource="@xml/searchable" />` this One inside `Activity` tag. Try adding this one.

Comment: @jaydroider what is @xml/searchable in meta data ?

Comment: Bro Give your `XML` resource file their in which `<item>` is defined. Like `android:resource="@xml/Your Item Search XML File Name" />`

Comment: is it worked or not?

Comment: @jaydroider No, its not working. Having same issue.

Comment: Make sure you have defined correct file name in resource xml metadata. Else i don't be able to assume as you are saying all the things are perfect.

Comment: @jaydroider Metadata thing did not work, but I resolved my issue by calling actionmode insteat of actionbar for search. Thanks for giving solution.

Comment: @AnkeshkumarJaisansaria did you please get any other solution if you get share the code

Answer (score 0):

Now we have toolbar in Android. So instead of ActionBar from Activity, use To
Tooolbar view as ActionBar.

```
  Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
        ActionBar ab = getSupportActionBar();
```

Now operate on ab. By default your activity show a action bar but Toolbar is hiding it. Also use menu item as

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_search"
    android:icon="@drawable/ic_action_search"
    android:title="Search for products"
     app:actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView"
     app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionView"
    />
```

Comment: In my OnCreate method, I already have have this piece of code. setSupportActionBar(toolbar).

Comment: adding actionViewClass="android.support.v7.widget.SearchView" worked, but I want to show my custom layout to the search bar

Answer (score 0):

You should implement something like this to get your "Search Field" working just fine:

```
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
   
   getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_search_list, menu);

  MenuItem searchMenuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);

  android.support.v7.widget.SearchView searchView = (android.support.v7.widget.SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(searchMenuItem);

    searchView.setQueryHint(getString(R.string.type_here_to_filter));

    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(new android.support.v7.widget.SearchView.OnQueryTextListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
            return searchForAnItemInTheRecyclerView(query);
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
            return searchForAnItemInTheRecyclerView(newText);
        }
    });

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your item on the menu xml.

```
app:actionLayout= "@layout/YourSearchLayout"
```

Answer (score -2):

Try to add the item like this in Menu.xml file:

```
 <item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:icon="@drawable/src"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"
    app:showAsAction="always|collapseActionview" />
```

Comment: He is not looking for this. He want to show `Edit Text` is not appearing. Please read Question and Comments first before Giving an Answer.

Comment: Exactly. My search icon is appearing. Only thing is that edittext is not showing.